# Shall I ask more questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I often read questions by [Franck](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/903/franck-dernoncourt) and I think "What kind of crazy stuff is he doing all day?". But obviously, his questions are well received - and he even gets good answers.

At the same time, I think "WTF, this is crazy stuff I have to deal with" (mainly for the insane legacy stuff at work) but at the same time I doubt that there's anyone else who would benefit from an answer.

Now I know that there's [no too localized](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/can-there-be-a-too-localized-question) content, but should I really waste your time with such localized questions?

Examples could be

- Refactoring tools for Java 1.1
- Java 1.1 class libraries
- Source code statistic tool that can handle Java classes with >20k lines per file (no, we did not reach the theoretical limit yet)
- Parser for INI files that does not follow Microsoft INI rules, supports comments and cross-section references
- Tools for Android 2.3 (with APK files for download, since our devices do not have access to a store)
- PC tools for debugging Android 2.3 over USB
- Browser Automation for Adobe Flex 2

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked before and doesn't pertain to this discussion, but why do you have two accounts?

Comment: It's not just what you ask,its how you ask it. Also there's always someone with a worse, more legacy setup than yours.

Comment: @Tom: My employer forced me to create an own account, so he knows which items I create during work time and which I create in my free time. I'm not happy with it - and since I have a new boss, I could ask him whether this is still necessary.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Hmm, that's kind of intrusive:/

Comment: Keep in mind that such questions are more likely to be [automatically deleted](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2457/903), unfortunately, so you may be wasting your time as well.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Now that I'm encouraged asking such questions I hope that the 5 upvoters from below upvote my questions at least once :-) Looking at my profile I don't see so many with 0 upvotes, so that's an acceptable risk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, please post such questions, since I have a lot of legacy knowledge as well and I could provide helpful answers.

Comment: Adding on to this - you're not the only one working with ancient technology. There's a decently high chance that these kinds of questions will help others. Ask away!

Answer (score -2):

No, the examples are really cruel. Nobody wants to recommend 10-year-old software anymore. Answers will not be helpful to anyone else at all.